# Joomla Component Formatting Form Inputs

Tags: forms, joomla

I want to be able to format a field in Joomla.  I'm creating a form that has a number of inputs and I want to format the inputs to have a yellow background and be of various lengths.  Currently my form is produced in the standard Joomla way:

```
 <div class="tablecol1">
  <?php echo $this->form->getLabel('dob'); ?>:&nbsp;&nbsp;
  </div>
  <div class="tablecol2">
  <?php echo $this->form->getInput('dob'); ?>
  </div>
```

I've looked through the JForm stuff but I can't figure out how to control the format of the generated input box?

help would be great thanks

Comment: Why not add a custom CSS stylesheet? You can target any input, as they have their own `id`s by default (at least in J!3.x).

Comment: Is it possible to add a class to the input box

Comment: If you set the `class` and the `labelclass` attributes in the form's configuration xml file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting a class for the inputs would be the quickest and easiest way as mentioned by MasterAM.  You can then style it however you wish using CSS.

If you need to change the HTML or particular attributes that are not possible to set through the default parameters, then the next option is to create your own field type.

You can either override the existing ones or create ones with new names.  For example you could copy the checkbox field (/library/joomla/form/fields/checkbox.php) into your own folder (/components/com_mycomponent/form/fields).

If you leave it as JFormFieldCheckbox it will override the default one.  If you rename it - e.g. `JFormFieldCustomCheckbox` then you can have your own one.

The primary function you will want to look at is `getInput()`.  This generates the HTML and will let you create your own input html with whatever attributes you wish.

To use custom attributes/settings from your form xml file, in your `getInput()` function you will use something like:

```
$fieldsize = $this->element['field_size'];
```